# How to check if selenium is working on browser on Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium

I am wondering if I can write the script that is working on the browser and I can see it.
Now, I am working on the project using selenium on Ruby, and they totally work on the headless mode but I want to change it to normal mode( which I can see that is working on the browser)

I have tried a lot but I don't know how to do it.

here is what I have tried.

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome, options: options)
driver.get("https://www.google.co.jp/")
```

and it returns the error like this.
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError (unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.)

> (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)   (The
> process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no
> longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

and this is the one that work fine but can't open a browser

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, url: 'http://chrome:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities: :chrome, options: options,)
```

Probably this is so basic thing on selenium so I feel sorry but any advice will be welcome.

Comment: Check out chrome version and your chrome driver version matches.

Comment: It's happening due to the chrome driver misplacement.

Comment: thank you. but the version is correct. these match

Comment: Which OS you are having?

Comment: I guess it is because of setting of docker. when I run the script on terminal it worked.

Comment: I leave you here. Take care.